# How to interpret the coefficient in a level-log regression

Tags: statistics, regression

I have a level-log regression of the form:

```
y = β⋅ln(x) + ε
```

I know that if we increase `x by 1 percent`, we expect y `to increase by β/100 units of y.`

My question is:

How does this generalize to other changes except `1%?` If we increase `x` by say, `10`, `50` or `100` percent, what is the expected unit change in `y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect changes like this.

```
y = β⋅ln(x) + ε

1. increase x by α [100α %] => x + αx => x(α+1) 
2. β⋅ln(x(α+1)) + ε 
    = β(ln(α+1) + ln(x)) +  ε 
    = βln(α+1) + βln(x) + ε
    = βln(α+1) + y(x)
```

Thus if you increase x by, y will be increased by βln(α+1)

```
α    |  βln(α+1)
-----|-----------------------
0.01 |  0.00995 * β ~ 0.01 * β
0.02 |  0.01980 * β ~ 0.02 * β
0.20 |  0.18232 * β ~ 0.18 * β
0.50 |  0.40546 * β ~ 0.41 * β
```